# Using 2 different MKAnnotationViews on one Mapview, one for own Position, one to show sth

Tags: iphone, annotations, mkmapview

How can i get it, that the current Location gets the normal Pin-Annotation and an Annotation made by own Software gets an Image as Annotation ?

I could believe with an if in the -(MKAnnotationView*)mapView(...) viewForAnnotation:
But on which property can i decide if its my own Annotation or if it is the Apple-Annotation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i have made an own class implementing the MKAnnotation-Protocol and an own selector.
In the -(MKAnnotationView*)mapView(...) i just try, if the selector is available. works